# why does tor browser take so long to launch on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tor

How long should it take for tor to launch? It  literally me takes 10 to 15 mins on Ubuntu. Does an yone know why or if anything can be done?

Comment: I have this exact issue. When I click the Tor icon it's about 10 - 15 minutes of nothing and then it suddenly pops up. Once loaded it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

TOR sends your requests through something like 5 IP addresses with high security,
and then the comes back through all the IPs again, making it very slow.

However, your case is still too extreme. I can make several guesses for reasons why.

It might be that your installation of TOR is defective. You could try to uninstall
it, download the latest version and re-install.

If your ISP is somehow detecting TOR, or the government sets up decoy nodes,
you might try to see how it goes when using a VPN. It should under normal
undisturbed conditions be slower, not faster, unless the conditions are abnormal.

Another possibility is that the TOR network you are connecting to has its
bandwidth all choked up. So try to connect to other countries.

Still another possibility is to use [Tor Bridges](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/bridges). The link explains how to find such a bridge, even an unlisted one
which might be safer.

Comment: Reinstalling tor and using a bridge hasn't changed anything. And so we're clear about whats happening, when I click on the browser, at first nothing seems to happen. But when it FINALLY pops up, everything works

Comment: It seems that it takes it time to find a useful node, but afterward all is fine. Why that happens may depend on local conditions.